# Где ошибка в тесте к компоненту(React)?

Tags: reactjs, юнит-тесты, enzyme

Проверяю такой тест. В самом компоненте на ComponentDidMount я подписываюсь на событие message и получаю высоту. Как мне это правильно проверить в тесте. Нужно вызвать событие message с нужной высотой, а потом проверить, получил ли iframe нужную высоту.

Где ошибка?

```
it(``, () => {
    const frame = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <Iframe
            title='Test'
            className="test-class"
        />);

    const data = {result: {
        height: 635,
        url: '/'
    },
        type: "test"};

    const event = new window.Event("message", {height: data.height});
    document.dispatchEvent(event);


    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(frame);
    expect(node.getAttribute('height')).toEqual('635');
});
```

Вот сам код

```
 componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('message', this.height);
}


height = event => {
    event = window.event;

        if (typeof event.data === 'string') {


            const eData = JSON.parse(event.data);
            const height = eData.result.height;

            if (height) {
                this.setState({
                    height
                });
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
};
```